# Reading a PGM file in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-formats

I'm trying to run the command:

```
[face,MAP]=imread('face1.pgm');
```

but I get an empty array for `MAP`. I was able to successfully read the file data into `face` though.

Answer (score 2):

[PGM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html) is a grayscale image format. There is no colormap. Were you expecting one? The normal behavior for `imread` is to return an empty colormap if the file didn't contain one.